# Median for a sequency with missing values in R

Tags: r, function, median

I’m trying to do a median like a function, for vectors with even and odd numbers (related to quantities of observations – the calculating method changes). I need to include an option for missing values as well. How can I do this? I need to do this without to use the ready median(x) in R. Is it possible? I have put bellow how I tried to do:

```
x<-c(1,2,3)
function (x, na.rm = FALSE) {
x <- x[!is.na(x)]

return(mediana = median(x))
```

Comment: for the odd length case `if (length(x)%%2) x[length(x)%/%2+1]`, and a similar one for the even, except average the two middles

Comment: What's wrong with using `median` for the final step (as in your post)? Homework?